# How to copy file buffer directly to google bucket from fastapi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, fastapi, uvicorn

How to send `.pdf` `UploadFile` object to google bucket using `gsutil`?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File
import shutil, os

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/file/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):

    # save the file stream to local drive
    local_path = "./drive"
    local_path = os.path.join(local_path, file.filename)
    with open(local_path, "wb+") as fp:
        shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, fp)
    
    # gsutil
    os.system(f'gsutil cp "{local_path}" "gs://bucket_drive"')

    return {"response": "done"}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: @Mause Currently I am saving the file to local drive and then copy the file to google bucket which is not ideal because it is taking a lot of time when we have 1000s of files. Is there a way I can do it directly without storing it in local drive.

Comment: @Mause And I am just looking for a fastest way I can send those files to bucket without delaying other operations in my API

Comment: I recommend using the python api instead: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python